# MySQL Workbench no me muestra el botón de "Apply", entre otros

Tags: java, mysql, base-de-datos, mysql-workbench, botón

MySQL Workbench no me muestra el botón de Apply ni Revert. Tampoco el output. Al costado no me aparece el navigator ni schemas, aunque eso descubrí cómo hacerlo del modo complicado. Lo principal es el apply.

Siempre que veo tutoriales tienen esas opciones y el mío no, soy principiante y no entiendo nada. Ya intenté bajando versiones anteriores y reinstalando, pero nada.